# Scaling or Thinning Bones

Tags: armature

I have created a dragon mesh. Eventually, it will fly.

Right now, I am trying to add a bone to the mesh (near the "elbow" of the wing), but it is a huge piece of mesh and the armature bone becomes huge, too i.e. it doesn't fit inside the wing. Please see what I am trying to do below and how it currently looks. Note that I am new to Blender.

Maybe it isn't a problem if the bone sticks out; I don't know. In the end, when animating, can I hide the bones and only see the mesh? If so, there would be no problem for the bone size, I guess. Tried to look this up on the internet, but could not find exactly this issue addressed. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Armature **never** shows up during a render. If it sticking out is annoying while modeling, you can choose between five options for its shape. To change, select the armature and go to the *Properties panel > Skeleton tab > Display dropdown* and choose. I would describe the five, but it would take a while, so I'll just say that I believe *Stick* is the smallest.

[image]

*Note that the image is a cropped version of one belonging to chichige bobo in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0qmTAhBDHQ) YouTube video.*

Lastly, just thought I'd add that *Octahedral* bones (what is currently displaying) do stretch out like in your third image, but only when using a *Stretch To* Constraint. You would not want to employ this for just basic rigging.

Answer (score 0):

When using B-Bones

ctl + alt + s "thins" the bones.

from memory this also scales the envelope.